# Laravel intervention to login post before start auth control

Tags: php, laravel

We imported some users from our old script.
But we can't decrypt this users password.
So I defined a default password to this imported users.
I have a `imported` column on my users table.

So I want to do this:
When a user post the login form I want to check user is imported or not by using user's email.

Like:

```
if (User::where("email", $email)->first()->imported == 1) {
            //change password parameter and then start auth proccess.
        } else {
            //nothing. just normal auth proccess
        }
```

If it's imported user, I need to change password parameter's value to my default password and make it successfully login. Then I will send a confirmation mail to this user and force change his/her password. If it's not a imported user, nothing gonna happen just make it login in normal way.

Note: We can use same password hash code instead of laravel's hash. But we don't want to do this.

So how can I intervention to login post before start auth control.

I just want to do: this imported users should be login without error. Because this user's password not gonna match with our db records. I defined a custom password like "123456". User will try his old password. But I want to change his old password with "123456" and user can login the system and I can send confirmation mail for change his password.

Comment: Maybe the events would help you?

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#events.

More precisely this: App\Listeners\LogAuthenticationAttempt

Answer (score 0):

First, the logic is bad for some security reasons. If I As a guest user or anonymous use happened to know an email then I can log in to the user account with an invalid or random password.

It is better to do it in another way. First, check the user's email, and if found one then email him a reset password link and don't log him in.

If the user owns the email address then he/she can reset his/her password and log in easily.

But if know what you are really doing then you can create your own login or `AuthenticationController`. and use your logic there. you can sign in the user by id without the default password. You don't need a default password in this case anyway because the end-user is not typing the default password.

Below is an example:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthencaticationController extends Controller{

  public function login(Request $request){

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    //use might be null so you should first check 
   // otherwise an error will occure because we cannot use the property of null or non-object
    
    if(is_null($user)) { 
      // redirect user back with error message
      return back()->withErrors(['email => 'Email is incorrect']);
    }

    // for readbility i prefer to create isImproted() method in User model
    // and return whatever to check if user is imported

    if($user->imported) {
     
     auth()->loginUsingId($user->id);
      
     $request->session()->regenerate();
      
     return redirect('email confirmation action path');

    }


    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect('redirect not imported users path');

  }

}
```

[Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#regenerating-the-session-id)

> Regenerating the session ID is often done in order to prevent malicious users from exploiting a session fixation attack on your application.

*Note that this just a simple way to do that you can refactor it in many ways.*